# What is the difference between center and body attribute in tiles definition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, apache-tiles

Tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Lets see"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp  "/>
        <put-attribute name="center" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" /> 
    </definition>
</tiles-definition>
```

This is how my template.jsp looks

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>       
        <td width="350"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

1) What is the difference between center and body attribute?
2) Can we give any arbitrary names to the attributes?
3) What are the other attributes other than the ones mentioned here?

Please provide some difference showing with sample images.

Comment: You should check the `/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp` file.

Answer (score 2):

```
What is the difference between center and body attribute?
```

As per your configuration there is not difference between center and body.

```
What are the other attributes other than the ones mentioned here?
```

In tiles you can define own attributes which will act as placeholders for html tags. Your main template will be `/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp` which will have attributes which you can replace with custom html tags based on the view you want to generate.

Read [this](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/) documentation for more information.

Comment: So, can I have a attribute like this  
<put-attribute name="ksdjbksjf" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />

Comment: May I know what you mean by custom html tags?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is duplication of same view.It should be ok if you remove the tag with  attribute name =center and keep the tag with attribute name=body.
However its up to you to keep both if you have requirements like that.
Yes its possible to give arbitrary names but it makes sense if you give the names like header,footer,body,left,right.